# Angled css tabs menu

Tags: css, menu, tabs

I have been given a design to implement that requires a horizontal menu like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jccZD.jpg

The tabs should have an active / hover colour and javascript is ok. Should work on ie8+

Usual Section > ul > li > a HTML structure.

I have done a bit of looking around and cannot find any examples. Is it possible / sensible or should I tell designer to go back to the drawing board.

Cheers

Comment: Have you [tried](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/) [CSS](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) [Triangle](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)? Anything?

Comment: Yeah - i have, you can get the shape but how do you get the text inside it. My understanding is that you are using the border to make the shape and the text must remain in the element. [link to codepen](http://codepen.io/ronaldroe/pen/osLbm)

Comment: wrong codepen see - [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Lgdpa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hashem recommended, you can use CSS Triangle. You posted a codepen but noted that the text was outside the "border" of the < li > element. In the past, I've overcome this by making the padding on the left / right side equal to that of the border and use no top/bottom padding. That causes the text to fit within the < li >.

```
padding:0 50px 0 30px;
```

Sorry, I am a brand-new user so I was not able to comment hence a new "answer" to the existing thread. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah - have been fiddling around with this for a while and it seems sketchy. I need the spacing between the tabs and also the reverse angles.